# Unable to create database via user input

Tags: php, mysql

I'm simply trying to check if a database with the same name exists (if yes, throw an error) else create it and display it has been created successfully. But after entering the database name, no database is getting created. What could I be missing ? (Is db.php even getting called ?? I think there should be some way for index.html and db.php to communicate , right ?)

This is my index.html

```
<form method="post" action="">
    Enter database name: <input type="text" name="db" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And my db.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  //check for the submit button pressed
    $dbname=$_POST['db'];     //store the database name in php variable
    $query= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','')or die("Error establishing connection");      //check for database connectivity
    $a="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ".$dbname;    //create a database if it doesn't already exist
    $q= mysqli_query($query, $a) or die("Database already exist.. please try   different name");
    echo "Your database ".$dbname." is successfully created";
    }
?>
```

Comment: CREATE database with `$_POST` u must need to learn about SQL injection

Comment: Hint: check either your database user having `CREATE`  privileges or not

Comment: @devpro yes he has the privileges (root)

Comment: then instead of `die("Database already exist.. please try   different name");` this error use `mysqli_error()` to get actual error

Comment: @devpro Sir there are lots of tutes on almost anything php/mysql but this particular thing I couldn't find anything relevant to my simple requirement.

Comment: r u getting this `Database already exist.. please try   different name` error or blank page?

Comment: action missing `<form method="post" action="">` should be `<form method="post" action="db.php">`

Comment: @devpro No error still, is db.php even getting called ?? I hink there should be some way for index.html and db.php to communicate , right ?

Comment: not calling bcoz u r not using action attribute in your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using action in your `<form>` here:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

You must need to use action to call `db.php` as:

```
<form method="post" action="db.php">
```

here, i am assuming, `db.php` and `index.html` both of them located at same directory.

**Side Note:**

Creating database by using user input form, without preventing SQL injection is not a good approach. use [PDO / prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection) to prevent with SQL injection.

**One more suggestion for future visitors:**

instead of `die("Database already exist.. please try different name");` use `mysqli_error()` to get actual error if your query not executed.